# Created a maven project in Eclipse, moved directory location, how to open it now?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I created a maven2 project in eclipse, and then I moved the folder to another location.

How can I open that project now in eclipse, I can't seem to find a 'open an exisiting maven' project or the like?

Opening the file pom.xml just opens the file, kinda stuck sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the M2Eclipse plugin for Eclipse, you can **right-click** in the **Package Explorer** view and then **Import... > Maven > Existing Maven projects**:

[image]

If you are using the maven-eclipse-plugin, then simply import it as an **Import... General > Existing Projects into workspace**.

Comment: where is the package explorer? I just see the project explorer.

Comment: Window > Show View > Package Explorer on the Eclipse menu, at the top of the window.

Comment: ok I changed to the 'java perspective' and I see package explorer tab now.  But right-clicking doesn't give me the 'import' option.  I do have the m2eclipse addon installed though, hmm?

Comment: @Blankman Then you must be in the Java EE perspective. But this doesn't matter, the **Import...** entry is there too (or access it through **File > Import...**)

Comment: yeah I did the import -> existing projects into workplace and then I get an error, with it referencing the old path where the project used to be.  I thought I installed the M2Eclipse, it is better it seems since I can import via the pom.xml

Comment: ok it is installed, when trying http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e it says it is already installed.

Comment: eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
java.version=1.6.0_18
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


Error
Sun Mar 14 22:43:24 EDT 2010
Working directory does not exist: E:/dev/eclipse/HrpSpider

Comment: @Blankman If you have m2eclipse, import it as an **Existing Maven Projects** as I wrote. If it doesn't work, then you must have something else interfering.

Comment: Hmm..could be the andriod plugin I installed, that is the only thing else I have. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try File->Import->General->Existing Project into Workspace.

[image]